# unresolved reference to getSignInResultFromIntent

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-authentication

Hi I'm new to Android Studio and I can't find anything thing online to fix this issue of unresolved reference. I follow a tutorial online to create a Google Sign in through firebase on my App using Kotlin. I Feel like this is an easy fix but I haven't found anything in which to fix this error.

The project can still run the app but it doesn't work properly with my indented UI.

Code screenshot and snip of it below.

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this,""+p0.errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}


companion object {
    private val PERMISSION_CODE =9999
}

lateinit var mGoogleApiClient:GoogleApiClient
lateinit var firebaseAuth:FirebaseAuth
//lateinit var alertDialog:AlertDialog

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
        val result:GoogleSignInResult = Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API.getSignInResultFromIntent(data) //Error here---  
        if(result.isSuccess) {
            val account:GoogleSignInAccount? = result.signInAccount
            val idToken:String? = account!!.idToken

            val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken,null)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(credential)
        }
        else{
            Log.d("EDMT_ERROR","Login Unsuccessful")
            Toast.makeText(this,"Login Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(credential: AuthCredential) { // changed from AuthCredential?
    firebaseAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->
            val logged_email = authResult.user.email
            val logged_activity = Intent(this@MainActivity,LoggedActivity::class.java)
            logged_activity.putExtra("email",logged_email)
            startActivity(logged_activity)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener{
            e-> Toast.makeText(this,""+e.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    configureGoogleClient()

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    /*alertDialog = SpotsDialog.Builder(0) //Github thing that i may have to fix
        .setContext(this)
        .setMessage("Please wait")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .build()   */

    btn_sign_in.setOnClickListener {
        signIn()
    }
}

private fun signIn() {
    val Intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient) //maybe add Intent:Intent!
    startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSION_CODE)
}

private fun configureGoogleClient() {
    val options = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN) // maybe change to options:GoogleSignInOptions! =
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
    mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this,this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,options)
        .build()
    mGoogleApiClient.connect()  // don't forget it
}
```

}

`

[Problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0izbj.png)

[Link to screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QxlU.jpg)

Comment: please add the problem verbally or as a picture here - when the picture link expires your question might become irrelevant for the future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to replace `GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API` with `GoogleSignInApi` on the line with the error. Make sure you read the API docs, like these: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi

Comment: Thanks!! That fixed it